# Writing a string to pdf with PyPDF2

Tags: python-3.x, pdf

I will read 130+ excel files in as lines of strings in Python. I want to write each line to a pdf. 
The whole excel file is just 1 A5 landscape sheet. I can batch print pdfs in a bash shell easily.

I import PyPDF2

I can create a pdf or a series pdf files with:

```
with open(path + fileName, 'wb') as out:
        pdf_writer.write(out)
```

but I'm too dumb to see how to write a string to this pdf. If I try to write a string variable, I just get errors. If I convert the string to bytes, I just get errors.

How do I get string into my pdf?

string = 'any old string'

Comment: From documentation: https://pythonhosted.org/PyPDF2/PdfFileWriter.html

class PyPDF2.PdfFileWriter - This class supports writing PDF files out, given pages produced by another class (typically PdfFileReader).

Comment: If only I could understand that! I've been reading it all afternoon! I can create and write to text files easily, but pdfs elude me!

Answer (score 4):

I know you asked for `PyPDF2` but more simple approach with `FPDF`:

```
# https://pyfpdf.readthedocs.io/en/latest/
import fpdf #pip3 intall fpdf

pdf = fpdf.FPDF(format='letter') #pdf format
pdf.add_page() #create new page
pdf.set_font("Arial", size=12) # font and textsize
pdf.cell(200, 10, txt="your text", ln=1, align="L")
pdf.cell(200, 10, txt="your text", ln=2, align="L")
pdf.cell(200, 10, txt="your text", ln=3, align="L")
pdf.output("test.pdf")
```

As you mentioned you dont understand, PyPDF doc so well so i think `FPDF` is a good start.

> PyPDF2 is more suited for reading and merging pdf files.

If you realy like to use PyPDF2 you could achieve text with `canvas`.

Comment: Thanks, I'll get fpdf! Looks simple! I need simple!

Answer (score 1):

One way (and the only way I see) to do this with PyPDF2 is with [annotations](https://pypdf2.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user/adding-pdf-annotations.html).

> ```
> writer = PyPDF2.PdfWriter()
> # Need to specify page size since there is no prior page to
> # draw size from.
> writer.add_blank_page(800.0, 800.0)
>
> annotation = PyPDF2.generic.AnnotationBuilder.free_text(
>     "Hello World\nThis is the second line!",
>     rect=(50, 550, 200, 650),
>     font="Arial",
>     bold=True,
>     italic=True,
>     font_size="20pt",
>     font_color="00ff00",
>     border_color="0000ff",
>     background_color="cdcdcd",
> )
> writer.add_annotation(page_number=0, annotation=annotation)
>
> with open(outputfilename, "wb") as fp:
>     writer.write(fp)
> ```

Comment: Thanks, I will try your suggestion. After this question, I delved into reportlab, which allows you to create any kind of PDF and place text or images anywhere. A bit tricky at first, but, once set up, reportlab is great!

Answer (score 0):

`PyPDF2` is very good choice when you need to change existing PDFs, but it requires knowledge of pdf format when you need to create PDF from scratch.

You might consider using a different library for this task i.e. `pdfkit` (https://github.com/JazzCore/python-pdfkit), sample program:

```
import pdfkit

pdfkit.from_url('http://google.com', 'out.pdf')
pdfkit.from_file('test.html', 'out.pdf')
pdfkit.from_string('Hello!', 'out.pdf')
```

Comment: Thanks, I'll try that! On the other hand, it can't be rocket science to write a string to a pdf. If I can do it 1 time with Pypdf2, then I'll know. Do you have that 'deeper knowledge'?

Comment: Have a look at PDF format https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PDF. You might craft a page, convert it to stream and write it with PdfFileWriter and this will work too.

Comment: Isn't pdfkit supposed to be really slow?